# Where do I place the commas?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

Which would be more appropriate?

**First quote:**

> Furthermore, corporations such as the American Diabetes Association
>   offer a variety of prizes for meeting certain fundraising thresholds.

or

> Furthermore, corporations such as the American Diabetes Association,
>   offer a variety of prizes for meeting certain fundraising thresholds.

**Second quote:**

> Randy Cohen, in his column, “The Ethicist,” also questions the
>   righteousness of offering incentives for donations in school.

or

> Randy Cohen, in his column “The Ethicist,” also questions the
>   righteousness of offering incentives for donations in school.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest

> Furthermore, corporations, such as the American Diabetes Association, offer a variety of prizes for meeting certain fundraising thresholds.
>
> Randy Cohen, in his column, “The Ethicist,” also questions the righteousness of offering incentives for donations in school.

since sometimes commas act effectively as parentheses, at other times as natural pauses in speach, and at other times they adhere to the traditional rules of English grammar (eg, both prior to and at the end of (within) quotations, etc.).

Comment: To me, the first sentence could go either way, depending on whether _all_ corporations (including the ADA) offer a variety of prizes for fundraising (comma), or if only corporations that are similar to the ADA offer a variety of prizes for fundraising (no comma).

Comment: @SomethingDark If the ADA is the *only* corporation to offer this, there is no reason to mention corporations at all. If *all* do, htere is no reason to mention the ADA. If *some* do (as implied in *such as*), I believe commas around the clause *such as the American Diabetes Association* are warrented. That said, I agree with your final statement.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be a comma between a subject and its verb. The second form of the first quote is therefore clearly wrong. The first form is fine. "Furthermore" and "Moreover" are technically adverbs, which don't require offsetting with a comma, but because they sound like phrases, it's common to do so.

For the second quote, the second form fails for the same reason. The first form is better, because the commas surrounding "The Ethicist" set it off as an appositive clause. The mission of many editors, professors, bosses and style guides however is to get you to use as few commas as possible, so in that light, consider using no commas at all in the second quote. Even though there's a speaking pause after "Randy Cohen", he's the subject, and the subject shouldn't be set off with a comma from the rest of the sentence. (That same rule.) Letting "column" and "The Ethicist" be juxtaposed without commas makes a noun clause instead of an appositive. Noun clauses like "Jack the Ripper" and "John the Baptist" are readily understood. Can you imagine putting commas after "Jack" and "John" in those cases?

Comment: 'There should not be a comma between a subject and its verb.' is not always the correct rule. For a parenthetical **not** marked by inverted commas, a comma may be the best choice: _Tony Cameron, the Prime Minister, could hardly be classed as a socialist._